# how to close overlay in jquery (event not bind)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how how to close overlay in jquery ?.Actually when I click on button I show `overlay` .On `overlay` there is `close` button.On click of close button I want to close overlay ? how I will achieve

here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/DdujoTZJBDdqSwBybGAM?p=preview

Code:-

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('body').append($('#overlay').html())
  })
  $('#closeBtn').on('click',function(){
    alert('close');
    $('.overlay').hide();
  })
})
```

Comment: It is about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '#closeBtn', function() {
    alert('close');
    $('.overlay').hide();
  })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to bind the *close* event, the close button isn't created yet. So you have to bind the event to a parent element in order to get dynamic element's events to work:

```
$('body').on('click','#closeBtn',function(){
    $('.overlay').hide();
})
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/IXQmv7xHG9D0AYo5ZPXp?p=preview)

Or even set the close event at the show event:

```
$('body')
      .append($('#overlay').html())
      .find('#closeBtn')
          .on('click',function(){
              $('.overlay').hide();
          })
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/yjJkI2MH4GQ88h56uVDn?p=preview)

Comment: `Or even set the close event at the show event` ? Why ? First solution is more sensible I guess :)

Comment: @Rayon just another option.

Comment: @Rayon I agree. Just wanted to show how it can be done in many ways.